# app.showMessage in compositionComplete no appears

Tags: javascript, durandal

I need to show a message in "compositionComplete", but the next code no work:

```
function compositionComplete(view, parent) {
        app.showMessage('This is a message.', 'Demo');
    }
```

The view was blocked and the `app.showMessage` didn't appear.

I use Breeze 1.4.1, Durandal 2.0, Knockout 2.3.0, Bootstrap 3.0, jquery 2.0.3 and in the shell `cacheViews:true`.

javascript console only show:

```
Binding plugins/messageBox 
MessageBox {message: "This is a message.", title: "Demo", options: Array[1], __dialog__: Object, selectOption: function…}
 system.js:75
```

I review the console and the problem appeared when exist errors of databind with ko or Q. But I need to show these errors with 'app.showMessage'.

I test in IE 10, Firefox 23, Google Chrome 29 but the problem persist in three browsers.

Comment: Did you properly load the `dialog` plugin within your `main.js` file?

Comment: yes I do. But the problem appeared when exist errors of databind.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information here to answer your question, but for clarity the code does work in a properly built module

```
define(['durandal/app'], function (app) {

    function attached() {
        app.showMessage('This is a message', 'demo');
    };

    function compositionComplete() {
        app.showMessage('This is a message', 'demo');        
    };

    var viewModel = {
        compositionComplete: compositionComplete,
        attached: attached
    };
    return viewModel;
});
```

You have another problem, keep your eye on your console to figure out what it is.

Comment: My javascript console no show any errors... the last line is 'Bindingplugins/messageBox[object Object]'.

Comment: I review the console and the problem appeared when exist errors of databind with ko or Q. But I need to show these errors with 'app.showMessage'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported "css/durandal.css"?

If you read here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!Topic/durandaljs/8g7DDCuvlpU you'll see how to fix it.